# Split a comma delimited string into an array and display on html page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

basically I'm making a page where the information from mySQL database will be displayed. I have a column named **topics** in the database where the string (VARCHAR) goes like this:

> Marketing, Business, Law, Medicine, ...

I'm trying to break up this string after a comma and display them in a single line one by one like this:

```
<h6>Marketing</h6>
<h6>Business</h6>
<h6>Law</h6>
<h6>Medicine</h6>
<h6>...</h6>
```

I already have a loop for other rows and I'm not sure if it's possible to make a loop in the loop, I'm not even sure if what i'm trying to achieve is possible but I belive it is. Here goes my full PHP code:

```
<?php
include_once '../handlers/db_conn.php';

$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM esc WHERE hosting_country = ?");
$sql->bind_param("s", $hosting_country);

$hosting_country = 'Poland';
$sql->execute();

$result = $sql->get_result();
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($resultCheck > 0) {

} else {
  echo '<p class="not_found">Nothing Found</p>';
}

while($escrow = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

?>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
  <div class="sec1_col1">
    <h2><?php echo $escrow['project_name'] ?></h2>
    <i class="fi fi-br-world"></i>
    <h3><?php echo $escrow['hosting_country'] ?></h3>
    <i class="fi fi-sr-calendar-lines"></i>
    <h3><?php echo $escrow['start_date'] ?> - <?php echo $escrow['end_date'] ?></h3>
    <h4 class="objectives"><?php echo $escrow['objectives'] ?></h4>
    <h5>Topics</h5>
    <h6><?php echo $escrow['topics'] ?></h6>
    <hr>
    <a href="#">Read more</a>
  </div>
</div>

<?php
}
?>
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to create another loop in this loop for  element, separate this string after a comma and display one by one in  tag? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT**

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: This is how I want it to look]

Comment: What is the key for the comma-delimited data? `topics`?

Comment: Yeah, that is the name of the column in mySQL database, that's what I need to fetch separately. I'll upload the picture of how I want it to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simple (and yes, you may have <s>as many</s> nested loops inside your code as you want):

Use [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split your string, then loop over it.

```php
<!-- inside your loop... -->
<h5>Topics</h5>
<?php foreach(explode(", ", $escrow["topics"]) as $topic) { ?>
<h6><?= $topic ?></h6>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Absolutely, as soon as it lets me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with a simple explode by comma, trim (to remove spaces) and join (could be empty, but a newline is nicer).

```
$topics = 'Marketing, Business, Law, Medicine';
echo join(PHP_EOL, array_map(fn($topic) => '<h6>'. trim($topic) . '</h6>', explode(',' , $topics)));
```

### Output

```
<h6>Marketing</h6>
<h6>Business</h6>
<h6>Law</h6>
<h6>Medicine</h6>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split into an array and then map the array into containing  tags:

```
function h6($n)
{
    return "<h6>$n</h6>";
}

$in = "Medicine,Arts,Law";
$components = preg_split("/,/", $in);
$html = implode(array_map('h6', $components));
echo($html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to explode

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
  $str = "Hello,World!,Beautiful,Day!";
  $arr = explode (",", $str);//;('Hello','World!','Beautiful','Day!');
  foreach ($arr as $item) {
    echo "<h6>".$item."</h6>";
  }
?>

</body>
</html>
```